# How do i put two pie charts side by side on matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have the following code below

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.pie(values,labels = labels,colors = colors,autopct = '%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Gender Composition in 1960')
labels = male_and_female_2016['level_1']
values = male_and_female_2016['value']
#settings and configs for the pie charts
colors = ['#FF8F33','#33FFDC']
explode = (0.1, 0)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.pie(values,labels = labels,colors = colors,autopct = '%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Gender Composition in 2016')
plt.show()
```

it show me like this
[image]

How do i get it to be displayed side by side?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `plt.figure` twice, `plt.pie` and `plt.title`, use:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6, 3))
# ...
axs[0].pie(values,labels = labels, colors = colors, autopct = '%1.1f%%')
axs[0].set_title('Gender Composition in 1960')
# ...
axs[1].pie(values,labels = labels, colors = colors, autopct = '%1.1f%%')
axs[1].set_title('Gender Composition in 2016')
# ...
```

See this example for inspiration:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-categorical-variables-py

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me. :)

Comment: You are welcome! I use https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html all the time when looking how to plot something... If you mind, you can set the answer as a working one for your case.